# Angular - PHP API No variables inserted in to database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been working on a way to push variables from my application to my database. It now succesfully makes a connection, but it doesn't push the variables into the database (It makes a new row, but the the variables are empty.)

I'll post my http.get

```
$scope.signupuser = function(info){
$scope.user = [];
$scope.user.email = 
$scope.user.voornaam = 
$scope.user.achternaam = 
$scope.user.postcode = 
$scope.user.woonplaats = 
$scope.request = $http({
    url: "www.test.com/example.php",
    method: "POST",
    params: { 
        voornaam: $scope.user.voornaam, 
        achternaam: $scope.user.achternaam, 
        email: $scope.user.email, 
        postcode: $scope.user.postcode, 
        woonplaats: $scope.user.woonplaats
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
$scope.request.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("inserted Successfully")
})
```

My example.php

```
<?php

include '../dbconnect.php';

try {
     json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
     print_r($_POST);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                users ( 
                     email, 
                     voornaam, 
                     achternaam, 
                     postcode, 
                     woonplaats
                ) VALUES (
                     '$email', 
                     '$voornaam', 
                     '$achternaam', 
                     '$postcode', 
                     '$woonplaats'
                )";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

I suspect there is an error in how example.php handles the delivered variables, but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

Error message for clarification

```
Array ( [{"voornaam":"gfa","achternaam":"g","email":"JohnDoe@gmail.com","postcode":"8271AT","woonplaats":"fdsa"}] => ) 
Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/www/vhosts/text.com/httpdocs/example.phpon line 13

Notice: Undefined index: voornaam in /var/www/vhosts/text.com/httpdocs/example.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: achternaam in /var/www/vhosts/text.com/httpdocs/example.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: postcode in /var/www/vhosts/text.com/httpdocs/example.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: woonplaats in /var/www/vhosts/text.com/httpdocs/example.php on line 17
New record created successfully
```

SECOND EDIT:

Print_r($_POST)

```
Array ( [{"voornaam":"Jogn","achternaam":"Doe","email":"johndoe@gmail_com","postcode":"3252AR","woonplaats":"Zwolle"}] => )
```

print_r($_POST[0])

```
   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/example.php on line 9
```

print_r($_REQUEST)

```
Array ( [{"voornaam":"Jogn","achternaam":"Doe","email":"johndoe@gmail_com","postcode":"3252AR","woonplaats":"Zwolle"}] => )
```

Comment: What's going on with all the `$scope.voornaam = //nothing` in the javascript?

Comment: Yea, Sorry that was still left over from trying to set values to the varirables and then sending it. To see if it was a problem within my javascript instead of sending the part where I send variables. Should've cleaned that up

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST)`; at all to see what is in there? Also try `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to check GET' etc.

Comment: I have the  print_r($_POST); . This prints out 
    
Array ( [{"voornaam":"gfa","achternaam":"g","email":"John_Doe@gmail.com","postcode":"8271AT","woonplaats":"fdsa"}] => )


So indeed, It gets the variables. Not it states that the indexes are undefined right under it! (when running example.php )

Comment: Are you using PHP 7 or is that actually a JSON array. You may need to use json_decode...

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6. I've added json_decode($_POST) but it doesn't like it. The documentation is pretty unclear (for me) on json_decode. Could you explain which variable I need to pass in the json_decode?

Comment: It's hard to tell from here...  it looks like POST contains an array. Try `var_dump($_POST[0])` first. or `print_r($_POST[0])` if you prefer.  It may be that the javascript is serialising the POST data into an array for some reason.  Square brackets [] = array, Curlies {} = object.  This is JSON notation and also object literals in PHP now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107617/discussion-between-martijn-bos-and-tim-ogilvy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this **with PDO prepared statements** instead, much safer, prevents SQL injection etc.

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
            users ( 
                 email, 
                 voornaam, 
                 achternaam, 
                 postcode, 
                 woonplaats
            ) VALUES (
                 ':email', 
                 ':voornaam', 
                 ':achternaam', 
                 ':postcode', 
                 ':woonplaats'
            )";

$params = array(
    ':email'   => $_POST['email'],
    ':voornam' => $_POST['voornaam']
    // etc
)
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute($params);
```

**In angular try:**  (taken from the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http))

```
var params = { 
    voornaam: $scope.user.voornaam, 
    achternaam: $scope.user.achternaam, 
    email: $scope.user.email, 
    postcode: $scope.user.postcode, 
    woonplaats: $scope.user.woonplaats
}
$http
    .post("www.test.com/example.php", params)
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log("inserted Successfully")
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I've changed it, but now it keeps saying "Undefined index: (place all of the variables here)"  I suppose this means that the variables don't even arrive at the document?

Comment: @MartijnBos the POST data is clearly there... did you copy my code exactly, using ':email' etc?

Comment: I've posted the error in the original post :) Just to make it more clear! It actually now posts :voornaam & :achternaam etc in my database

Answer (score 0):

try to use a `serialzier` to your data and I prefer to use `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`.Don't forget to add it to controller dependencies and you code should be

```
var data={ 
    voornaam: $scope.user.voornaam, 
    achternaam: $scope.user.achternaam, 
    email: $scope.user.email, 
    postcode: $scope.user.postcode, 
    woonplaats: $scope.user.woonplaats
}
$scope.request = $http({
url: "www.test.com/example.php",
method: "POST",
data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data),
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```